# Flying your own plane from Nome AK US to Anadyr Russia

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, russia

Or to be more precise, what were they supposed to do?   They flew their own [Beech Bonanza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Bonanza) from [Nome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome,_Alaska), Alaska, to [Anadyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadyr_(town)), Chukotka Autonomous Okrug, Russia (in the eastern tip of the country).  They claimed to have gotten the proper visa.

Here's [the video in question](https://youtu.be/YEi_m5C1-Jc?t=1193).  I cued it up to 19:53 where they start to talk about what happened.

Now, Anadyr is on the south bank of an inlet.  The airport is on the north side, and they're connected with a ferry:  [At 25:48](https://youtu.be/YEi_m5C1-Jc?t=1548) the narrator explains that if you cross the water to enter Anadyr, that's what needs special permission.   Does any of that make sense?

What really happened?  And was it a trivial violation as they made it sound, or is it a serious violation that would prejudice future attempts to enter Russia?

Comment: Somewhat related: Mathias Rust's flight that landed on the Red Square in 1987. The number of rules and regulations violated on that day was *staggering*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathias_Rust

Answer (score 4):

Beyond the passport and Russian visa that most people need to enter Russia generally, there are [two additional separate permits](http://%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/vlast/organy-vlasti/apparat-gubernatora-i-pravitelstva/poryadok-oformleniya-razresheniya-na-vezd/pamyatka-vyezzhayushchemu_en.php) required to visit the Chukotka region, which is normally closed to nonresidents:

- The rasporyazheniye (распоряжение), which permits entry into the region (only foreigners require this permit, Russians do not), and
- The propusk (пропуск), which permits crossing the regional border and going to specific locations in the region (everyone needs this permit).

I also watched this video last week, and I already knew that this region was rather difficult to get into. From the limited detail in the video, I can't be entirely sure which of the two permits they were missing.

Comment: By "region" do you include both Anadyr and the airport across the inlet, in the same region?  Or are the two of those separate enough to require a permit to go *between* them i.e. using the ferry?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "region" means the Chukotka Autonomous Region, as stated on the official website. Your other question is a lot more into the weeds of Russian law than I was really intending to go; the map shows me that the airport is outside the city limits, so I suspect that probably means one permit allowed them to go to the airport and they needed both permits to go into the city. For people who want to travel there, I expect the difference doesn't mean much; only making sure to have both permits is the important part.